# Change NodeJS local server access URL

Tags: node.js, localhost

Is it possible to change the URL used to access my local NodeJS server?

For instance, I have a Node server running on port 3000, so I can access this server directly through:

> http://localhost:3000/

And other users on my network can access it through:

> http://[MY_IP_ADDRESS]:3000/

Is it possible to forward this server to a local URL, like http://example/

I know that, in order to remove the port from the URL I need to bind the app on port 80, but I can't find anything about changing de URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very clear what you want, to be honest and your set-up. You use local computer or server in local network?

If you want URL in your local network isolated - that's not possible hence the URL protocol forwards requests from domain name to certain ip address.

If you want only internal access in your local network you only need to know your local ip address and make sure your firewall allows local connections. Depending on your OS run ip check in cli and voila - that's your ip.

If you want external connections then you need to have a static ip address which you should obtain from your internet provider and afterwards you need to alter you router settings and set up port-forwarding to your local machine. It will then listen to external connections on certain port and forward it to your local machine where nodejs listens (itself or through web-server). Here you can redirect your domain URL name via A-record to your static ip address of your router and port-forward to local machine.

Check out [this](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/) guide for most routers for external port-forwarding.

UPD: checkout [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/233575/use-name-instead-of-ip-address-for-home-network)

Comment: The NodeJS server is running in my local computer, users in my LAN can access it through http://10.220.64.134:3000, however it would be easier for people at my office to type something like http:// myapp/ in the search bar and access my NodeJS server. Something like "renaming" the hostname for my server. Don't know if it's possible though.